# Is there a way of getting the compiler to initialize a string with the enclosing method name?

Tags: c#, methods, compiler-construction, static

Our C# codebase have several methods that create error messages that include the method's name. Can I get the compiler to statically insert the method name for me? I know I could do something with reflection, but I'd rather not.

Amongst other things, I'm seeing quite a few copy-paste errors where the exception handling from one method is copied to another, without the method name changing.

```
    public void Method1()
    {
        try
        {
            DoStuff();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            HandleError("Method1", details);
        }
    }
```

Rather than include the string `"Method1"` (and `"Method2"` up to `"Methodn"`) is there a way of telling the compiler to insert the current method name there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NET 4.5 you can use the [CallerMemberName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) attribute. Your `HandleError` method would then look like so:

```
void HandleError(YourDetailsClass details,
                [CallerMemberName] callingMethod = null)
```

and you'd simply use

```
HandleError(details);
```

Comment: Very nice. I actually wasn't aware of this at all!

Comment: Do you know if this information is set "statically" - i.e. at compile time, or dynamically at run time? I guess JIT confuses things, as you now have "compile time at run time" as well.

Comment: Very good question - I guess I never was obsessed enough with performance to check, so thanks for making me. I can confirm this is done at compile time, so I guess another good reason to use this in most scenarios.

Comment: It's not just performance - when compiling with optimizations, some methods may get merged/inlined. I don't know if this could ever change the method name given, but if it could, I want to avoid it.

Comment: I don't have any example to back this up, but I'd bet that resolving the name is done before any optimizations to avoid any issues. After all, MSDN clearly states that one of the uses is logging, so I don't believe they'd mess this up.

Comment: Right - in this answer, but answers involving reflection or stackframes may potentially suffer from this. Anyway, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 1):

you can use [MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod.aspx) which returns [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx)

```
using System.Reflection;
```

and then

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    HandleError(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, details);
}
```

Comment: Indeed. Much cleaner than my attempt.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead your is also quite good, because you can use HandleError without passing Method name, gets my vote

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the `StackTrace` and `StackFrame` classes in `System.Diagnostics` to retrieve the method name:

```
private void HandleError(Exception ex) {
    var st = new StackTrace ();
    var sf = st.GetFrame (1); // get the previous method that called this
                              // (not this method)

    var previousMethod = sf.GetMethod ();

    var errorMessage = string.Format("Error in method {0} with Exception {1}", 
                           previousMethod.Name,
                           ex.Message);
}
```

Example:

```
void MyMethod() {
    HandleError(new Exception("Error here"));
}
```

`errorMessage` would contain: `Error in method MyMethod with Exception Error here`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can try with this:

```
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace st = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
string methodName = st.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name;
```

And you will have the name of your running method.